# Python - Model a railroad using networkX

Tags: python, networkx

I'm a railroader and would like to optimize train movements for # of trains moved in a 24 period.  I've begun reading documentation on networkX and pySim.   Let's say there are 5 trains that are eastbound and 3 that are westbound.  From West to East, these are the nodes: Desmet, Missoula, Bonner, McQuarrie, Clinton.  How would I build a model that would figure out the best way to move the 5 eastbound and 3 westbound trains assuming that the edges between nodes are 'single track' (i.e. this restricts trains to moving one at a time between nodes)?

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edge('desmet','missoula',weight=1.5)
g.add_edge('missoula','bonner',weight=1.5)
g.add_edge('bonner','mcquarrie',weight=0.1)
g.add_edge('mcquarrie','clinton',weight=0.1)

print nx.shortest_path(g, 'bonner', 'desmet')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.
Rather than a focused programming question, you seem to be asking for a tutorial and completion of your network design.

Comment: @Prune I don't think this is an inappropriate question - as I understand it, the question is basically "how do I add an idea of time, or motion, to a graph in networkx"?  I think the answer is to use [flows](http://avrilomics.blogspot.com/2015/09/finding-maximum-flow-in-network-using.html), but I don't know enough about it to answer myself.

Comment: Perhaps the question should be clarified, however, to specifically "how can I represent movement / temporal change in networkx", rather than "how to I solve the entire problem statement".

Comment: Sorry if it's inappropriate.  Maybe my approach with networkx is wrong.  The problem is much like a 'towers of hanoi' problem that is multi directional.  So maybe the better question is, how do you solve a multi-directional 'towers of hanoi'?

Comment: @Jasher: "appropriate" depends on what you expect from us.  "How would I build a model" seems too broad to me.  If you need coding help, you haven't yet reached a level of detail I feel is appropriate to SO.  If you're looking for design help, I feel that this falls into the "tutorial" category that belongs elsewhere in StackExchange.  **However**, some extra clarification on your part might bring this into a more useful area for us.